# Multiprocessing - Why don't Processes run continously

Tags: python, multiprocessing

While experimenting with the multiprocessing module I've noticed that the processes do not run continously but rather seem to stop and continue at random.

With the following code the difference between updating the time in p1 and comparing it to the current time in main process is **most **of the time very close to 0 (~x.e-07). However sometimes it starts to deviate looking like that:

... beeing x.e-07 for quite some time then slowly starts to deviate further

```
1.200009137392044e-06
6.699992809444666e-06
1.1800031643360853e-05
1.7000013031065464e-05
2.2199994418770075e-05
... cut out middle part ...
0.0009208000265061855
0.0009266000124625862
0.0009312999900430441
0.0009370999759994447
0.0009419000125490129
0.0009475999977439642
**0.0009531999821774662** highest point of deviation 
**9.600014891475439e-06** goes back to close to zero values
```

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def p1(t, e):
    while True:
        t.value = time.perf_counter()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shared_timestamp = multiprocessing.RawValue('d')
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=p1, args=(shared_timestamp, 2))
    p.start()

    while True:
        print(time.perf_counter()-shared_timestamp.value)
```

I can't seem to understand why that's the case and i haven't found any explanations either.
I used multiprocessing.RawValue('d') so that no locks could be the issue. With multiprocessing.Value('d') it's the same picture.

I thought that maybe the shared memory portion caused this issue so I tried this code:

```
import multiprocessing


def p1():
    while True:
        print("p1")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=p1)
    p.start()
    while True:
        print("main")
```

Here the "p1" and the "main" prints are not always alternating but sometimes are printed repeatingly (like 100x "main" then alternating than 50x "p1").

I thought that processes would run without interuptions in a parallel and concurrent way.
Does anyone has an explanation for this behaviour?
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Nothing about process/thread scheduling is guarenteed. Your alternating output lines up with this executing on a single-core machine.

Comment: There are other processes on your machine which want their fair time-slice to run.